# Netbeans xdebug debugging fails on Drupal 7

Tags: netbeans, drupal-7, xdebug

I have debugging set up for PHP, and it works exceptionally well on my Drupal 6 sites but when I try to debug my only Drupal 7 site, program execution doesn't stop at the break points.
I've set the url to myexample.com, instead of myexample.com/index.  I have a positive netbeans-xdebug connection showing at the bottom of the screen and the breakpoints show in the debugger window.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to clean this one up with a fresh installation of Drupal 7.  Removing and reinstating the folder as a Netbeans project didn't work, but building a fresh site with the latest Drupal 7 code, then copying all my modules over, did the trick.